# Calculating sum for the current date Dax (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to Power BI and I'm trying to solve the following problem: new customers are the ones that placed a new opportunity and haven't had any opportunities >0 in 3 prior years. I created a new 'Calendar for New Logo' table that has all the dates and I have  'Opportunity for new logo' table with all customers' opportunities.

So I calculated 3 measures:

1)

```
Running Total =
VAR MaxVisibleDate =
    MAX ( 'Calendar for New Logo'[Date] ) - 1
VAR Previous3YearDate =
    EDATE ( MaxVisibleDate, -36 )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Opportunity for new logo'[Amount_USD for Closed and Commit] ),
        DATESBETWEEN (
            'Calendar for New Logo'[Date],
            Previous3YearDate,
            MaxVisibleDate
        )
    )
```

2. 

```
Opp_sum =
VAR CurrentDate =
    MAX ( 'Calendar for New Logo'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Opportunity for new logo'[Amount_USD for Closed and Commit] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Calendar for New Logo' ),
            'Calendar for New Logo'[Date] = CurrentDate
        )
    )
```

3. 

```
NewLogo =
IF (
    ( 'Opportunity for new logo'[Opp_sum] > 0 )
        && ( 'Opportunity for new logo'[Running Total] = 0 ),
    1,
    0
)
```

I see that the issue is somewhere with Opp_sum (I don't get numbers where there're supposed to be ones), and also in NewLogo I don't get total sum of all the "1"'s.
Please help me to understand how to fix my DAX.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make your DAX code readable to humans via https://www.daxformatter.com/. However, your formulas don't make much sense w/o sample data.

Comment: Opportunity_for_New_Logo table:

Comment: You need to share the data model and sample tables.